# A heavyweight and a lightweight version of the same object

Tags: java, object

For a project we are developing, we are in need of a lightweight and a heavyweight object of the same entity class. We are having a simple solution, but need to know if there is any better solutions from the expert perspective. Our solution is as follows:

```
public interface User{

//Some variables and methods 

}

public class LightWeightUser implements User{

//Lightweight code goes here

}

public class HeavyWeightUser implements User{

//HeavyWeight code goes here

}
```

We are planning to use hibernate for database handling part.

Comment: Is implementing lazy loading not a good enough solution for you?. Although its a suggestion, lazy loading works, most of the time. Just mark the optional parameters as lazily loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible alternative:

```
public class User {
    //Light-weight code goes here.
}

public class HeavyWeightUser extends User {
    // Heavy-weight code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach to consider would be to use delegation insted of inheritance.

```
public class HeavyWeightUser { 
//HeavyWeightUser properties here
//....
private User user;
//exposing user properties here 
public Something getUserProperty(){return something;}
public void serUserProperty(Something something){this.user.setSomething(something);}
}
```

This has advantages like:

1. you are free to inherit form parent class because you didnt use up this option jet
2. you can expose only properties that make sence
3. your object are not so tightly coupled as with inheritance, which usualy means you can change your implementation with more ease.

Disadvantages:

1. More coding

Answer (score 1):

I would use a decorator pattern for this, if you have the non functional requirement that your code should be easily upgradeable. It would look as the following:

```
//first define a basic layout for your class
public abstract class User{
       public abstract String foo(String bar);
}

//then extend it and implement real behavior
public class concreteUser extends User {
    public String foo(String bar) {
        ...
    }
}

//now comes the interesting part... the decorator. At first we need to define a layout for our decorators, that extends your implementation
public abstract class UserDecorator extends User {
    @Override
    public abstract String foo(String bar);
}

//now you are ready to do everything you want
```

With this 3 classes you can now start to "decorate" the heavyweight and lightweight behaviour in every way possible to your class. Lets have an example and create a decorator:

```
public class AsdfUserDecorator extends UserDecorator {
    private final User user;

    public AsdfUserDecorator(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String foo(String bar) {
        //do stuff
        ...
        //propagate everything to other decorators (this is the magic)
        return foo(user.foo(bar));
    }

    private String additionalHeavyweightStuff(String asdasd) {
        return blubb;
    }
}

//and another one
public class QwerUserDecorator extends UserDecorator {
    //no changes in the class in this example... its the same as AsdfUserDecorator....
    private final User user;

    public AsdfUserDecorator(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String foo(String bar) {
        //do stuff
        ...
        //propagate everything to other decorators (this is the magic)
        return foo(user.foo(bar));
    }

    private String additionalHeavyweightStuff(String asdasd) {
        return blubb;
    }
}
```

Now you can decorate a user with the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    User user = new concreteUser();
    user = new AsdfUserDecorator(user);
    user = new QwerUserDecorator(user);
    user.foo("sadf");
}
```

This is a really powerful pattern, I hope I could help you.

Have a nice day.